# Convert geopandas shapely polygon to geojson

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I created a circle using geopandas and it returned a shapely polygon:

```
POLYGON: ((...))
```

I want this same polygon as a geojson object. I ran across this:

```
shapely.geometry.mapping(shapelyObject)
```

which returns this:

```
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((570909.9247264927, 125477.71811034005)...}
```

But when I try to map this in mapbox it does not show anything. I think maybe it is not fully a geojson object.

Comment: Check https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-geojson/

Comment: @PaulVarghese so do I just need to wrap it in `"geometry": { }` ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you don't want to create this dict manually, you can also rely on `geopandas` creating it:

```
In [1]: import shapely.geometry

In [2]: import geopandas

In [3]: shapely_polygon = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)])

In [4]: geopandas.GeoSeries([shapely_polygon]).__geo_interface__
Out[4]: 
{'bbox': (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
 'features': [{'bbox': (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
   'geometry': {'coordinates': (((0.0, 0.0),
      (0.0, 1.0),
      (1.0, 0.0),
      (0.0, 0.0)),),
    'type': 'Polygon'},
   'id': '0',
   'properties': {},
   'type': 'Feature'}],
 'type': 'FeatureCollection'}
```

(Note that this gives a FeatureCollection and not a single feature.)

Or to a string (or file):

```
In [4]: geopandas.GeoSeries([shapely_polygon]).to_json()
Out[4]: '{"features": [{"bbox": [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], "geometry": {"coordinates": [[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]], "type": "Polygon"}, "properties": {}, "id": "0", "type": "Feature"}], "bbox": [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], "type": "FeatureCollection"}'
```

Comment: I get this: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '__geo_interface__'

Answer (score 29):

Shapely returns a python dict where all the coordinates are in tuples. You need to convert to JSON in order for mapbox, etc... to properly accept it.

```
json.dumps(shapely.geometry.mapping(shapelyObject))
```

Comment: Of course it ended up being as simple as `json.dumps()`

Comment: How to load it back and create shapely object?

Answer (score 12):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
features = [{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {}, 'geometry': shapely.geometry.mapping(shapelyObject)}]
```

Now you can try to map `features` in mapbox.
Hope this helps.

Reference:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213717/geometry-workflow-from-shapely-to-geojson

Answer (score 9):

To write a standard geojson object using pandas you shall use the driver provided by `fiona` as recommended in the [documentation](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html?highlight=to_file#writing-spatial-data)

```
gdf.to_file('path/to/file.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

See `import fiona; fiona.supported_drivers` for a list of fully supported drivers

Answer (score 4):

Assume `polygon_list` is a list of `shapely.geometry.Polygon`.

```
geo_dict = {}
geo_dict["type"] = "FeatureCollection"
geo_dict["features"] = [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": a} for a in [geometry.mapping(b) for b in polygon_list]]
my_geojson = json.dumps(geo_dict) # str in json format
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the driver provided by fiona:

```
data=shapefile.to_file("file.geojson",driver='GeoJSON')

data=geopandas.read_file("file.geojson")

data
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide more details about your answer? For instance, you could add how dnd why your solutions works, what does the user that posted the question was missing, etc.. This will help other people that reach the post in the future to understand more about your solution. Thanks

Comment: geopandas uses fiona for data conversion ,fiona has drivers to do so e.g creating shapefile,geojson etc from geodataframe.if you need to chack drivers in fiona just type   >import fiona    >fiona.supported_drivers the results should be {'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw', 'ARCGEN': 'r', 'PCIDSK': 'r', 'SUA': 'r', 
'DGN': 'raw', 'SEGY': 'r', 'MapInfo File': 'raw', 'GeoJSON': 'rw', 'PDS': 'r', 
'FileGDB': 'raw', 'GPX': 'raw', 'DXF': 'raw', 'GMT': 'raw', 'Idrisi': 'r', 
'GPKG': 'rw', 'OpenFileGDB': 'r', 'BNA': 'raw', 'AeronavFAA': 'r', 
'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw'}

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [PyShp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp)

```
import shapefile

with shapefile.Reader("shapefile.shp") as shp:
    geojson_data = shp.__geo_interface__
```

or

```
geojson_data = shapefile.Reader("shapefile.shp").__geo_interface__
```

example usage:

```
>>> geojson_data["type"]

'MultiPolygon'
```

Answer (score 0):

With geopandas, you can do:

```
with open("out.geojson","w") as f:
    f.write(gpd.GeoSeries([shapely_object]).to_json())
```